# Draw multiple overlines in Qt rich text

Tags: html, qt, richtext

I want to display logic equations in a QTextBrowser. It would be a lot better if I could draw overlines to symbolise the "not".

Right now I am able to draw one overline using text-decoration:overline :

```
Not(A)  = <span style="text-decoration:overline"> A </span>
```

But it doesn't work if I want multiple overlines. For example the following equation :

```
Not(A or not B) = <span style="text-decoration:overline"> A or <span style="text-decoration:overline"> B </span> </span>
```

Is there a solution or a workaround to be able to do this?

Comment: I thought it could be used in math equations for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MathML is not HTML, and `QTextBrowser` supports a simplified variant of HTML. It knows nothing of MathML. Alas, it might be a relatively simple change to the layout engine to implement this aspect of MathML, though. Worth looking into it I'd think.